# Rabbit MQ delay after last message

Tags: rabbitmq

I know there is a delay option in messages.

But I need this scenario:

- Execute the task.
- After execution wait for 30 seconds.
- Execute the next task.
- After execution wait for 30 seconds.
- Execute the next task.
- ...

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you've provided, this could just be part of the task processing callback in your application:

1. A new message comes in, and triggers your callback
2. Execute the task
3. Acknowledge the message
4. Run `sleep(30)` or whatever the equivalent is in your programming language of choice
5. Return from the callback

As long as your entire callback operates synchronously in a single thread, the next task won't be processed until it returns.